# Insufficient Storage Message - can't install apps - over 4gb free space - rooted

Tags: storage, navbar

First symptom was disappearance of navigation bar. Tried to d/l app to control nav bar, got the insufficient storage mesage. Yet I have over 4 gb free. I am using a Sero 7 Pro, with a 64gb SD card. I have read answers in other posts, have tried some, but filesystem on Sero is different; tried to locate large log file, can't find one, although com.android.vendors may contain something. Can't use fsck as there's no /etc/fstab. Have been working at this for three days, using posts on "insufficient storage", but nothing works so far.

Comment: It is likely that your device is unable to store apps (or at least the particular apps you want to install) on the SD card but only on its internal storage chips, and those may be full even though there is plenty of space on the external card.

Comment: My internal storage shows over 4gb of space. Nothing to do with the external SD card. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Does "adb shell df" work?  If so, edit the output into your question.  Otherwise provide the output of "adb shell mount"